# Populating a dictionary of lists with values from 2 columns of a DataFrame

Tags: python, list, dictionary, for-loop

If I have a DataFrame that stores values from 2 columns (A & B) from a CSV file, how would I populate a dictionary using a for loop to get the values from the DataFrame?

I need to store the rows of A B pairs like this..
A_&_B_sets = {1:[A1,B1],2:[A2,B2],…}

```
A_&_B_sets = {1:[A1,B1],2:[A2,B2],…}
for i in (1,n+1):
  A_&_B_sets[i] = i * I
```

I am quite lost. Any help greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have `df` like this:

```
   Column A  Column B
0         1         4
1         2         5
2         3         6
```

Then you can do:

```py
A_and_B_sets = {}
for i, (_, row) in enumerate(df.iterrows(), 1):
    A_and_B_sets[i] = [row["Column A"], row["Column B"]]

print(A_and_B_sets)
```

to print:

```py
{1: [1, 4], 2: [2, 5], 3: [3, 6]}
```